# ToastNotifications sent from PowerShell disappear from Action Center

Tags: powershell, toast

I'm using this code to send notifications from PowerShell script. PowerShell itself is launched by (persistent) Java application.

```
[Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotificationManager, Windows.UI.Notifications, ContentType = WindowsRuntime] > $null
[Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument, Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument, ContentType = WindowsRuntime] > $null
[Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotification, Windows.UI.Notifications, ContentType = WindowsRuntime] > $null
$xml = New-Object Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument
$template = "<toast><visual><binding template=`"ToastText02`"><text id=`"1`">Title</text><text id=`"2`">Test results</text></binding></visual></toast>"
$xml.LoadXml($template)
$toast = New-Object Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotification $xml
[Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotificationManager]::CreateToastNotifier("sbt").Show($toast)
```

They pop up on the screen and are visible in Action Center for while but quickly disappear. Notifications sent by the XAML app with the same code stay there for quite some time. Is there a way to change behavior of notifications sent via script?

Comment: Are you sure that "sbt" is the correct `applicationId`?

Comment: Well, it does display notifications and for some reason `CreateToastNotifier` can't be called without parameters.

Comment: I'm thinking that since the PowerShell task probably exits immediately after showing the notification, the Action Center looks at it and thinks "process not running anymore = fit for expiration". Whereas if you use the Java app's `applicationId`, it might figure that the notification is still relevant

Comment: I've tried sending notifications from PowerShell interactive app by wrapping the code above into a loop and they disappear too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must set a registry key for each `AppID` whose notifications you would like to persist in the Action Center.

For example, if you want your `irssi` notifications to persist, add the key: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Notifications\Settings\irssi` with a DWORD named `ShowInActionCenter` with value `1`.

Thanks to "Passing By" for the solution in [this article's](https://deploywindows.info/2015/12/01/powershell-can-i-use-balloons-toasts-and-notifications/) comments, and Mattias Fors for creating the article.

Update: You can also toggle this in your "Notifications & actions" Settings on a per-app basis.